# Recuperar informações do certificado digital

Tags: c#, criptografia, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

Estou trabalhando com arquivos em PDF assinados digitalmente PKCS#7. Dei uma pesquisada na internet e não consigo encontrar uma forma de recuperar as informações do assinantes.

Usando a classe `SignedCms` eu consigo até obter algumas informações quando eu faço o `decode` do arquivo, dentro do atributo `Certificates`, mas não consigo manipular elas, por exemplo, pegar o nome do assinante e colocar em string.

Alguém já trabalhou com isso?

Answer (score 2):

Como você citou, vou considerar que você tem acesso à propriedade [Certificates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.certificates(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe [SignedCms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms(v=vs.110).aspx).

Essa propriedade Certificates representa uma collection de [X509Certificate2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx)

A classe X509Certificate2 é a classe que representa as informações do certificado. Nesse caso o certificado que fez a assinatura.

Nessa classe você encontrará a propriedade [SubjectName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.subjectname(v=vs.110).aspx) que é a propriedade que contém o nome do assinante.

Então você pode dar um foreach na propriedade Certificates, um exemplo :

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
            foreach (var certificado in signedCms.Certificates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(certificado.SubjectName.Name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Ou** você pode ser mais direto, extraindo o certificado do arquivo p7s:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Temp\MeuPDFAssinado.p7s");
            Console.WriteLine(cert.SubjectName.Name);
            Console.ReadKey();        
        }
    }
}
```